# NuGet restoring packages unnecessarily

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have the following project structure:

`MainSolution\
    |
    +---> SharedProject\
    |         |
    |         +---> SharedProject.csproj
    |         +---> packages.config
    +---> SubSolution\
    |         |
    |         +---> packages\
    |         +---> SubSolution.csproj
    |         +---> SubSolution.sln
    |         +---> packages.config
    +---> packages\
    +---> MainSolution.sln`

`MainSolution.sln` is the main solution, referencing numerous projects, including `SharedProject.csproj`.
`SubSolution.sln` references only `SubSolution.csproj` and `SharedProject.csproj`.

`SharedProject.csproj`'s package references point to `..\packages\` (i.e. `MainSolution\packages\`).
`SubSolution.csproj`'s package references point to `packages\` (i.e. `MainSolution\SubSolution\packages\`).

NuGet is installed into Visual Studio as an extension.

**The issue**

I open `MainSolution.sln` in Visual Studio and build, NuGet restores all packages required by `SharedProject.csproj`, the packages are correctly placed in `MainSolution\packages\`. This is as expected.

I open `SubSolution.sln` in Visual Studio. I check `SharedProject.csproj`'s package references, which all point to the expected location (`MainSolution\packages\`).

I now build `SubSolution.sln`, NuGet restores all packages required by `SharedProject.csproj` and `SubSolution.csproj`. **However**, it doesn't detect that `SharedProject.csproj`'s required packages are already present on disk - it restores (downloads) those packages *again* and puts them in the current solution's `packages` directory, i.e. `MainSolution\SubSolution\packages\`. So now the packages are unnecessarily duplicated.

**The question**

When building `SubSolution.sln`, why does NuGet (and/or Visual Studio) choose to duplicate the packages referenced by `SharedProject.csproj` into the current solution's `packages` directory - instead of just using the referenced packages that already exist in the `MainSolution\packages\` directory?